# Dense simple smooth immersed curves in manifolds.

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, curves

The [irrationally sloped line in the torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_winding_of_a_torus) is a smooth, simple, immersion of $\mathbb{R}$ into $T^2$. This line is even **dense** in $T^2$ (thus not all injective immersions are embeddings).

When I tried to concoct a curve with similar properties in $\mathbb{R}^2$ I found it much more difficult and eventually threw up my hands in defeat.

So I'm curious:

- Is there a smooth, simple, immersed, dense curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (or $\mathbb{R}^n$)?
- If not, is there a smooth, simple, immersed, dense curve in an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (or $\mathbb{R}^n$)?
- In general, which smooth manifolds $M$ admit a smooth injective immersion $\gamma:\mathbb{R}\to M$ such that $\gamma(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $M$.

An answer to any of these would be extremely enlightening. Thanks in advance.

Comment: By "simple," do you mean injectively immersed?

Comment: If you demand injectivity this is not as obvious to me, though I still guess that it's true for any manifold. Here's a sketch of how to do it non-injectively for $\Bbb R^2$. Enumerate the rationals in $(0,1)$ as $q_n$. Now draw a curve that first traverses $q_1 \times [0,1]$, loops around, and comes back and tranverses $q_2 \times [0,1]$ at twice the speed, then $q_3 \times [0,1]$ at four times the speed, etc... eventually (in finite time) you have traversed a dense subset of $[0,1]^2$. Now put a bunch of these things together to traverse a dense subset of $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: @JackLee Yes. My understanding is that "simple curve" and "injective curve" mean the same thing. Unless "simplicity" does not rule out self-tangency.